# Apply filter to binding source in Windows Store App

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-store-apps

I've got a Windows Store App with a ViewModel property of type `ObservableCollection` which is bound to a control on the page

I'd like to apply a filter, expressed by code, to the binding to ignore items with certain properties.

In WPF this can be done using the Filter on a CollectionSourceView but it seems this does not exist for Windows Store Apps?

Comment: Unfortunately, to do this you'll either have to add logic which returns the filtered `ObservableCollection` or write your own `FilteredObservableCollection` class. I've done the latter so that I could also add sorting.